# C++, возникновение исключения при обработке другого исключения

Tags: c++, исключения

В общем, ситуация такая.

Я разрабатываю реализацию `Trie` (префиксное дерево) и столкнулся с неприятной (пока только теоретической) проблемой.

Дерево, которое я разрабатываю, должно обеспечивать гарантию безопасности при исключениях: если с деревом не удалось что-то сделать, то структура остается в том же состоянии, что и до начала операции.

Например, если посреди процесса вставки выяснилось, что памяти больше нет (или возникла другая проблема), тогда происходит подтирание того, что не успело сконструироваться до конца. Все оборванные операции откатываются. Незаконченные ветки уничтожаются.

В какой-то момент я заметил, что в нескольких местах происходит дублирование кода. Конкретно кода, который поднимается вверх по дереву и уничтожает каждый узел ветки, у которого нет потомков, и список хранимых значений которого пуст.

Эта функциональность нужна при:

- обработке провалившейся вставки;
- при удалении элемента из структуры;
- в деструкторе.

Ее я вынес в отдельный метод, и вдруг понял, что этот метод может генерировать исключения.

То есть, получилось что-то вроде:

```
void insert(...)
{
    // ...
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        try
        {
           erase_branch(...);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            throw;// ???
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

Повторяю, проблема пока что теоретическая, потому что `erase_branch()` может сгенерировать исключение лишь в том случае, когда структура дерева нарушена, например из-за логической ошибки при реализации.

Я практически уверен, что переход от исключений к кодам возврата проблему не решит, потому что вместо падения программы мы получим структуру с некорректным состоянием.

Единственный вариант побороть это - добавить в структуру флаг о том, что структура находится в противоречивом состоянии.

Подскажите, верно ли мое понимание данной ситуации?

Может быть, помимо флага корректности существует другой способ, чтобы не обрушивать всю программу, но при этом сообщить, что структурой дальше пользоваться нельзя?

Comment: Вообще ничего не понятно.

Comment: в чем вопрос? )

Comment: Вопрос в том, что делать, если возникло исключение, мы начали его обрабатывать, откатывая незаконченные действия, и в этот момент возникло еще одно исключение?

Comment: Если в момент обработки ошибки возникла невозможная ситуация (нарушен какой-то инвариант), нужно не исключения бросать, а assertы использовать.

Comment: Если нужно что бы некий код отработал без исключения - его нужно обвернуть в try-catch. Если ошибка в catch - то код в catch нужно обвернуть снова в try-catch. Можно хоть 10 раз обвернуть в try-catch  `try { /*1*/} catch { try {/*2*/} catch { try {/*3*/} catch {} }}`, но... если возникает "бесконечность" - то вы не верно продумали алгоритм. Исключительная ситуация должна приводить к тому, что программа отработает. Как вариант - часто делают "пропуск" участка кода, который не может обработать ошибку. Как по-мне - флаг "ошибка" - хороший вариант.

Comment: @nick_n_a, бесконечность не возникает. Я говорю о том, что исключение возникает при откате изменений. То есть, я перехватываю второе исключение, да, но я не могу вернуть контейнер в корректное состояние.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно попробовать скомбинировать варанты

```
void insert(...)
{
    // ...
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        try
        {
           erase_branch(...);
        }
        catch (...)
        {
            m_inconsistent = true;
            throw std::runtime_error("Error inserting data.");
        }
        throw;
    }
}
```

...

вызывающий код:

```
try
{
    trie.insert(...);
}
catch(const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;

    if (trie.is_consistent() == false)
    {
        // Обработка несогласованного состояния / завершение работы
    }
}
```

Но вообще ваша логика верная, если возникло исключение при обработке исключения, его надо обработать. Эту обязанность можно возложить на вызывающую сторону (тогда ваш вложенный блок трай-кэтч переедет в вызывающий код) либо делать самому

P.S. решение 2 - это сделать обработку несогласованного состояния в вашем методе insert, но после обработки выбросить оттуда специфичную ошибку (пронаследованную от std::exception). К сожалению в вопросе мало данных, чтобы дать более осмысленный ответ

Answer (score 2):

`std::terminate` будет, это прописано в стандарте. Именно поэтому не нужно допускать выброса исключений за пределы деструкторов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но вопрос совсем не в этом. Я знаю, что написано в `Стандарте`.

Comment: Тогда в чем вопрос? "Откат" должен делать деструктор, если внутри деструктора что-то поломалось - вы можете разве что стукнуть куда-то в глобальный лог, что оно поломалось - деструктор все равно дойдет до конца и удалит объект, ваш флаг будет хранить просто негде.

Comment: Откат не всегда должен делать деструктор. Например, вы вставляете элемент в красно-черное дерево. Наделали кучу всего, но до того, как закончили операцию, - возникло исключение. Например, память кончилась. Вы начинаете откатывать все операции и натыкаетесь на еще одно исключение, которое не позволяет вам закончить откат.

Comment: Если у вас получается это "не всегда", вы где-то не соблюдаете RAII

Comment: Возможно, вы правы.